# i still having problems with Jquery-ui with MVC 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

since sveral days i am trying to fix issues with Jquery-ui i am using Visual 2010 and the MVC 4 i correct the bundle and the layout to render scripts and the CSS here my code :

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<hgroup class="title">
<h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>

<article>

<div>
<label for="date">Select a date:</label> <div id="mydate"> <        @Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("mydate") </div>
</div>
</article>

<aside>
<h3>Aside Title</h3>
<p>
    Use this area to provide additional information.
</p>
<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
 </ul>
 </aside>
```

**and here is the sources code from Chrome :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>About - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.js"></script>

    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title"><a href="/">your logo here</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                        <ul>
    <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Log in</a></li>
</ul>

                </section>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">

        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

   <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <hgroup class="title">
<h1>About.</h1>
<h2>Your app description page.</h2>
</hgroup>

<article>

<div>
<label for="date">Select a date:</label> <div id="mydate"> < <input data-jqui-dpicker-   dateformat="dd/mm/yy" data-jqui-type="datepicker" id="mydate" name="mydate" type="text"    value="" /> </div>
 </div>
 </article>

 <aside>
 <h3>Aside Title</h3>
 <p>
    Use this area to provide additional information.
 </p>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</aside>
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; 2014 - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved
i was missunderstanding the way it wroks it was solved by adding some javascript